# code blocks cyclic shift

Tags: c++, c

I am new to C programming and have been trying to execute this program to shift the digits.
Ex.
I want 4567 to undergo right cyclic shift then it would become 7456.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
using namespace std;
int main()  
{
  int num;
  scanf("%d",&num);
  int temp=num;
  int flag=0;

  while(temp!=0)
  {
    temp=temp/10;
    flag++;
  }
  int r=num%10;
  int s=num/10;
  int k=pow(r,flag);
  int crs=k+s;
  printf("%d",crs);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: [tag:c] or [tag:c++]? Pick one...

Comment: Please format your code

Comment: its c++ sry i forgot

Comment: I am sorry please can u be more specific. I could nor understand what u wanted to say

Comment: To be fair, the problem in the question is not dependent on whether you use C or C++. But true, the code is not properly written is either as it stands.

Comment: @Abhay Goyal What is the question?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow i just want the number to make a right cyclic shift i.e. 456 becomes 645

Comment: @Abhay Goyal Well, then what is the problem?

Comment: The problem is that i have used the code as posted but am not getting the result.

Comment: @AbhayGoyal This call int k=pow(r,flag); does not make sense. You need to use a power of 10 something like int k = pow( 10, flag ) * r;

Comment: Ya. Thnx for that but its is showing a nuber less than the expected.

Comment: Ex.-567 becomes 756 but its shows 755

Comment: 'Thanx got the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use math to find how many digits in a number without for loop. just use floor(log10(number)).

```
int main(){

 int val = 11023;

int rem = val%10;

int positions = (int) floor(log10(val));

int left_digit = rem*(int) pow(10,positions);

printf("%d\n", left_digit+val/10);
```

}

Answer (score 1):

The thing you're doing wrong is the handling of the rightmost digit (in the original number). You don't want to take that to the power of `flag`. You want to take `10` to the power of `flag` and multiply it with the least significant (the rightmost) digit.

You should also be careful when counting the digits and determining how many steps you should shift the least significant digit. If you for example have `123` you have three digits, but you should only shift the least significant digit two steps to the left (and the rest one step to the right). Special thought might go to the case when the number is `0` - you'll get zero out anyway, which is probably what you want. Also you should consider what to do about negative numbers.

Something like:

```
#include<stdio.h>

#include<math.h>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
  int num;
  scanf("%d",&num);
  int temp=num;
  int flag=0;

  while(temp!=0)
  {
     temp=temp/10;
     flag++;
  }
  int r=num%10;
  int s=num/10;
  int k=r*pow(10,flag-1); // <- here's the fix
  int crs=k+s;

  printf("%d",crs);

  return 0;
}
```

Then of course there's some details. If you're programming C++, you shouldn't include `stdio.h` or `math.h`. Instead you should include `cstdio` and `cmath` (some may complain about using `cstdio` and say you should use `iostreams` instead, but that's just a matter of oppinion).

Comment: I did what you said and it has helped

Comment: but ya its printing somewhat the wrong result. When i entered 567 it showed 7056

Comment: Why is it adding an additional 0??

Comment: The reason for the additional `0` is that `flag` is the number of digits of the number (not counting leading zeroes). The least significant digit is shifted that many steps to the left. I fixed that too in the answer.

Comment: when i changed flag to flag-1, it is printing the number before the actual number to be printed

Comment: @AbhayGoyal That's odd. With `567` as input I get `756` output, just as required. It look's like you've done a typo - sure you didn't write `pow(10,flag-1)-1` or similar?

Comment: @skyking I dont know but i have tried numerous times

Comment: Thnx. got the answer

Answer (score 0):

This statement

```
int k=pow(r,flag);
```

does not make sense. You should us at least

```
int k=pow( 10,flag-1) * r;
```

But if the function is not overloaded for the type int then it can convert the operands to type `double`.

In fact there is no need to use the function.

The program can be written the following way

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    while ( true )
    {   
        const unsigned int Base = 10;

        std::cout << "Enter a non-negative number (0-exit): ";

        unsigned int x = 0;

        if ( !( std::cin >> x ) || ( x == 0 ) ) break;

        unsigned int multiplier = 1;

        for ( unsigned int tmp = x; tmp /= Base; ) multiplier *= Base;

        std::cout << "The shifted number is " << x / Base + x % Base * multiplier << std::endl;
    }        
}
```

Its output might look like

```
Enter a non-negative number (0-exit): 567
The shifted number is 756
Enter a non-negative number (0-exit): 0
```